# Create thumbnail using Java running on headless mode

Tags: java, image, opencv, hipi

How to create a thumbnail for an image using java application where X11 not available . I tried using **javascalr,im4java** but all working if X11 present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am able to run in headless mode using this below code

`static { 
    System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
    System.out.println(java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless());
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it would be easiest to install some dummy display driver. This could be a good place to start:

http://cosmolinux.no-ip.org/raconetlinux2/dummy_radeon_nvidia.html